# How do I set up multiselect using freemarker? Submit a "cat" list to choose from

Tags: html, freemarker

*Request form
<@spring.formMultiSelect or something else*

```
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add Expenses Operation</legend>
        <form name="expOperationForm" action="" multiple="true" method="POST">
            Operation amount: <@spring.formInput "expOperationForm.operationAmount" "" "text"/> <br/>
            From Account Id: <@spring.formInput "expOperationForm.fromAccountId" "" "text"/> <br/>

          !!!  Categories: <@spring.formMultiSelect ??? /> <br/>  !!!

            <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
        </form>     
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

*in controller*

```
model.addAttribute("cat", categoryService.getCategoriesList());
```